# WP_Query no posts with tax_query

Tags: wp-query

When I add a new WP_Query, everything works, but if I add a 'tax_query' with a taxonomy, it doesn't pull the posts. post_count would always be 0.

```
    $products = new WP_Query([
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'tax_query' => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'show_product_on_only_premium',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'yes',
                'operator' => 'AND',
            ]
        ]
    ]);

    echo var_dump($products);
```

I've played with the tax_query with different values and I've had no luck. 
This works on production but not locally and I can't figure out why. 
edit> my database has the taxonomy

Please help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: the array syntax with bracket for php <5.4 does not work see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772534/php-difference-between-array-and maybe it's the problem?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @AndreaSomovigo. Unfortunately that's not the issue. I have php 7+ but I switched it to array(...array(... etc and still no luck.

Comment: It might be the `operator` field, but you shouldn't need an entire tax_query for this

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks for getting back to me! I've used it without the operator and no luck. Of course if I put 'NOT' I'll just get everything and not the request.

Comment: As an aside, avoid `NOT` type operators like the plague, the cost for the DB is extreme, whereas filtering out in PHP or with multiple API calls, is significantly faster

Comment: Are you sure these are posts of type `post` and not `product`? And that it's `yes` and not `Yes`? That the posts publish date are all in the past, and that they all have the `publish` post status? And that no `pre_get_posts` filters are messing with the query?

Comment: You may be onto something with $post_type. I've switched it to most of the post_type available and I havent had much luck. 
As for pre_get_posts... I'm going to have to look up what that means. 
Thank you for helping me with this @TomJNowell!

Comment: Are these WooCommerce products? Or a custom post type? Clearly what you're querying for is not what you have, how is the `show_product_on_only_premium` taxonomy registered?

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm embarrassed to say I have no idea. 
If I look in the database under wp_Term_Taxonomy and filtered by Taxonomy is 'show_product_on_only_premium  I can see the entries. 

It's completely separate from post_type so maybe that part is wrong but the questionable part is that it works in production just not locally. I guess that's why I'm a bit puzzled. I wonder if having it as a custom post or a wooCommerce product might be the reason why it's not working.
It's not my code maybe the lead dev has a different dev environment to make it work. I'm just the intern.

Comment: Thank you for all your help @TomJNowell. You've definitely got me closer to a solution!

Comment: if it's a custom post type then setting `'post_type' => 'post'` will definitely not work. The `post_type` must match the type of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by just avoiding post_type since I had no idea what it was.

```
   $products = new WP_Query( array(
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'show_product_on_only_premium',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => 'yes',
            ),
        ),
    ) );
```

I tried to do it again with another taxonomy and I was so frustrated that it was still giving me no posts but it worked in production. Well it turns out my database locally has count: 0 but in production has count: 7. *face palm*

Answer (score 1):

Your query can be simplified to this:

```
$products = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'show_product_on_only_premium' => 'yes',
]);

echo var_dump($products->posts);
```

The culprit was likely the `'operator'=>'AND'`, the default value is `IN`, so changing your original query to use `IN` instead of `AND` would also work, as would removing the `operator` parameter as the default is also `IN`

Comment: Thank you for the tip, @TomJNowell. I'll definitely keep that in mind. Unfortunately putting it as  'show_product_on_only_premium' => 'yes' didn't help but damn is that really good to know I could just do something like that. Thank you!

Comment: Tom, it will work only if this taxonomy registers query variable ;)

Answer (score 1):

> You can use below code

```
   $products = new WP_Query( array(
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'show_product_on_only_premium',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => 'yes',
                ),
            ),
    ) );
```

Comment: `'relation' => 'AND'` it is not necessary here.

Comment: Yes i agree with you but above example  'operator' => 'AND', written